# How can I launch a download from the internet using command prompt?

Tags: download, command-prompt

I want create a program than launch a download from the internet using a command of command-prompt. 
Do you know this command ?

Comment: On linux it's called `wget`. Not sure about other OS's but this question seems more appropriate for the [Super User exchange site](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: The link below might be helpful -http://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the command :  `powershell -command "& { iwr http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/8/83/Fanta-Logo.png -OutFile logo.jpg }"`